# PDFBox PDFMergerUtility unstable on JavaFX application

Tags: java, javafx, pdfbox

My JavaFX application was downloading PDFs from the server, rotate to portrait if the PDF is landscape, and then merge all the PDF files into one single PDF file to print it out.

Everything went fine except the program will randomly stuck at outputting the merged PDF or adding one of the PDF files to PDFMergerUtility(which I am using PDFBox 2.0.11 and tried 2.0.9 also). Because my application requires a ProgressBar and TextArea to show the current action or status, I used a Task in my controller page. When the program hangs, it didn't enter any exception or print any message but completely stops the background action.  I have tried small amount of files (<50 files) and large file tests (>1000), but they all have the same results of absolutely normal or randomly hangs.

Below are the code of my controller program:

```
public class ReadDataPageController implements Initializable {
    public long startTime;
    public long stopTime;
    @FXML
    private Button btnNext, btnCancel, btnPrevious;
    @FXML
    private Label infoLabel, time, total;
    @FXML
    private ProgressBar progBar;
    @FXML
    private TextArea textArea;

    public Task<String> dlTask() {
        return new Task<String>() {

            @Override
            protected String call() throws Exception {
                DownloadUtil dlutil = new DownloadUtil();
                StringBuilder textStr = new StringBuilder();
                List<String> dlList = mainApp.DL_LIST;

                // Download PDF files from FTP
                super.updateValue(textStr.append("Preparing files for download...\n").toString());
                for (int count = 0; count < dlList.size(); count++) {
                    String PDFLink = dlList.get(count).getPDFLink();
                    super.updateTitle("Downloading file" + PDFLink + " ...");
                    super.updateValue(textStr.append("Got " + PDFLink + "\n").toString());

                    try {
                        dlutil.exec(PDFLink);
                        // downloaded location will be stored inside List DownloadUtil.pdfList
                    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
                        super.updateValue(textStr.append("Link not found for " + PDFLink + "\n").toString());
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        super.updateValue(textStr.append("Error while downloading " + PDFLink + " :" + ex.getMessage() + "\n").toString());
                    }
                    super.updateProgress(count + 1, dlList.size() * 3);
                }
                super.updateProgress(dlList.size(), dlList.size() * 3);
                super.updateTitle("Download action has finished.");
                super.updateValue(textStr.append("Download action has finished.\n").toString());

                // Rotate downloaded PDFs
                super.updateTitle("Preparing files for PDF rotation...");
                super.updateValue(textStr.append("Preparing files for PDF rotation...\n").toString());
                for (int i = 0; i < dlutil.pdfList.size(); i++) {
                    try {
                        String fileName = dlutil.pdfList.get(i);
                        rotatePDF(new File(fileName));
                        super.updateValue(textStr.append("Rotating PDF ("+(i+1)+" of "+dlutil.pdfList.size()+")...\n").toString());
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        super.updateValue(textStr.append("Error:" + ex.getMessage() + "...\n").toString());
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    super.updateProgress(dlutil.pdfList.size() + i + 1, dlutil.pdfList.size() * 3);
                }

                if (PRINT_OPTION == PrintType.PRINT) {
                    // Merge downloaded PDFs
                    super.updateValue(textStr.append("Preparing files for PDF merging action...\n").toString());
                    PDFMergerUtility pdfutil = new PDFMergerUtility();
                    for (int i = 0; i < dlutil.pdfList.size(); i++) {
                        try {
                            String fileName = dlutil.pdfList.get(i);
                            pdfutil.addSource(fileName);
                            super.updateTitle("Adding files (" + (i + 1) + "/" + dlutil.pdfList.size() + ")");
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            super.updateValue(textStr.append("Error:" + ex.getMessage() + "...\n").toString());
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        super.updateProgress(dlutil.pdfList.size()*2 + i + 1, dlutil.pdfList.size() * 3);
                    }
                    // Output merged pdf
                    try {
                        pdfutil.setDestinationFileName("../odt/merge.pdf");
                        pdfutil.mergeDocuments();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    super.updateTitle("Merged all PDFs.");
                }

                super.updateProgress(100, 100);
                super.updateTitle("All action has been finished.");
                super.updateValue(textStr.append("All action has been finished, press Next to choose your printing option.\n").toString());
                return textStr.toString();
            }
        };
    }

    /**
     * Rotates PDF images 90 degree if the PDF is portrait
     * @param resource the PDF file path
     * @throws InvalidPasswordException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void rotatePDF(File resource) throws InvalidPasswordException, IOException {
        try {
            PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(resource);
            int pageCount = document.getNumberOfPages();
            System.out.println("Reading file: "+resource+", total page="+pageCount);
            for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {
                PDPage page = document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().get(i);
                PDPageContentStream cs = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.PREPEND,
                        false, false);
                Matrix matrix = Matrix.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(90), 0, 0);
                cs.transform(matrix);
                cs.close();

                PDRectangle cropBox = page.getCropBox();
                if (cropBox.getWidth() > cropBox.getHeight()) {
                    System.out.println("ROTATE "+i+"th");
                    Rectangle rectangle = cropBox.transform(matrix).getBounds();
                    PDRectangle newBox = new PDRectangle((float) rectangle.getX(), (float) rectangle.getY(),
                            (float) rectangle.getWidth(), (float) rectangle.getHeight());
                    page.setCropBox(newBox);
                    page.setMediaBox(newBox);
                    document.save(resource);
                }
            }
            document.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any reason that may cause the PDFMergerUtility unstable, maybe because I used a Task outside or because I missed something crucial?

Comment: You say the program hangs. Are you sure the operation of the task actually got stuck? Or did probably a `Throwable` stop its execution? You can check using a `try {...} catch (Throwable t) {t.printStackTrace();}` around the content of `call` on one hand and triggering a thread dump when you have a stuck-program situation on the other hand. The only concrete cause I can think of is an out-of-memory situation...

Comment: Note: It's unnecessary to use `super.methodName` unless you override a method.

Comment: @mkl While I was testing my program, no exception showed in console, and the weird thing is that it happens both merging large or very small amount of files, the program will literally stuck at pdfutil.addSource(file) or pdfutil.mergeDocuments(). But I will do a few tests with printing out the throwable later and check if the real problem is on Task itself.

Comment: @fabian Thank for your advice, I will be updating my code with that one:)

Comment: @evanshwu If you again observe a stuck situation, retrieve the thread dump (on Linux use `kill -3` on the process) and try to find the current stack trace of the Task. If it really is stuck, it should show the specific code it's stuck at.

Comment: Note that JavaFX's `Task` silences uncaught exceptions, so if an exception was thrown that your code didn't catch - you won't see it in the console. You can try adding a [`onFailed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#onFailedProperty) handler to the task, or monitoring its [`exception`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#exceptionProperty) property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bingo! The exception was OutOfMemoryError, and Task from JavaFX made it silence.

I added the following code while initiating the task and it will handle the exceptions:

```
task.setOnFailed(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>(){
    @Override
    public void handle(WorkerStateEvent event) {
        Throwable th = task.getException();
        System.out.println("Error on Task:"+th.getMessage());
        th.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

To avoid OutOfMemoryError, I split the merging job into 100 pages per merging job, and save as multiple merged PDF files.